# How do I pull title from my database to create a hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, pouchdb

so I'm using PouchDB/Vanilla JS to create a database for a project I'm working on. I want to use the effect below:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity

My problem is, I want to be able to pull

```
thisFilm.title
```

from my javascript and have the title display when the image is hovered over (the image is also pulled from my database, so it's not like there's an image tag I can add it to manually)

How would I go about doing this? I'm not sure if this is the part you need but here's how i've pulled the image from the database onto the page:

```js
let db = new PouchDB('films');

      let radios = document.getElementsByName("sort");
      radios[0].addEventListener("change", getFilmList);
      radios[1].addEventListener("change", getFilmList);

      getFilmList();

      function getFilmList(){
        db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: radios[0].checked}).then(function(films){

          let listContents = '';


          for(let i = 0; i < films.total_rows; i++) {


            let thisFilm = films.rows[i].doc;

// this part
            let image = '<a class="btn" href="viewFilm.html?id=' + thisFilm._id +'"><img class="filmImage" src="' + thisFilm.image +'"></a>';

            listContents += '<div class="filmRow">'+ image + '</div>';
          }

          document.getElementById('filmContainer').innerHTML = listContents;

        })
      }
// until here
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', georgia, arial;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: left;
}

.sortFilms {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff6699;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.newFilm {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff6699;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.form {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

#formTitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.col {
  padding: 20px;
}

input,
textarea, select {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing:border-box; }
}


.tagline {
  margin: 0;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

#modifyFilmButton {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row  {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }

  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }

  table tr {
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  table td {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.oldFilm {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
}

#oldTitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  background: #ff6699;
}

.reviewImage {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.filmRow img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.filmRow {
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#filmContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sorting {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@6.3.4/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>

    <header>
      <img src="img/rv-logo.png">
      <p class="tagline">Want to know whether or not it's worth paying to watch a certain film or not? See what we think first!</p>
    </header>

    <div class="sortFilms">
    <h2 id="formTitle">Latest reviews</h2>
    <p class="sorting"> Sort by:
      <label>Ascending <input type="radio" name="sort" checked/></label>
      <label>Descending <input type="radio" name="sort"/></label>
    </p>
    <div id='filmContainer'></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I you can access `films.rows[i].doc._id` and `films.rows[i].doc.images`, why can't you access `films.rows[i].doc.title`?